# Art of War by Sun Tzu study group

Tags: discussion

We will be using an [annotated, free, and online](http://changingminds.org/disciplines/warfare/art_war/sun_tzu_annotated.htm) version of the book.

**What does this have to do with Anime and Manga?**
All the major generals during the sengoku period studied the book (Oda Nobunaga, Toyotomi Hideyoshi, and Tokugawa Ieyasu). Any works featuring them could have mentioned the book.

**So why a study group for the book?**
Because its interesting, was written 1500 years ago, has influenced war, business, and anything requiring strategy. It still applies today, and the study group's aim is to see how it applies, and specifically, how it applies to the interests of the members of the study group.

Art of War study group will start when I've nailed down a time and a format.

**TIME:**
Since the current members are in the US, Europe, and Australia, a tentative time of Friday to Sunday, 6-9pm Houston time, which corresponds to 9am-noon  Sydney time, and midnight to 3am London time.

**COMMUNICATION FORMAT:**
Either AM.SE chat or Discord. Will consider other formats.

**DISCUSSION FORMAT:**
Round table discussion. Look at that week's phrase(s) and describe how it relates to something in your life or how it could apply to certain realistic situations. Anything to drive a discussion really. This is fluid and can change if we find something better to drive discussion.

**MEMBERS:**

- ton.yeung(myself)
- armin
- quill
- krazer
- jnat

**SUBJECT TO CHANGE**
Rather, expect changes as we get through a few discussions and members provide their opinions on what went well and what didn't.

Please let me know if you want to participate by posting here if the time and format is okay. I will post the time and the link to wherever the discussion will be held here.

Comment: I assume we're talking about weekends? Also, that time conversion seems off to me

Comment: I believe that fixed it, right?

Comment: @JNat yes, thanks, I had it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Time would be best if we could arrange it around 6-7pm HT, that's between 1 and 2am CEST. And of course Friday to Sunday.

Concerning the format, it doesn't really matter, but preferably something I already have, which is:

- Skype
- Hangouts
- SE chat

Answer (score 0):

The timeslot you mention would work for me. Do you have any particular weekend in mind?

Any of the proposed mediums would work well for me. Do you have a proposed format for the session itself? I mean, is it a sort of debate, or a lecture, or something else entirely? 'Cause depending on the format, one medium might be more suitable than another.

Comment: Probably two weeks from now. A member is out of town next weekend. Format is more of round table discussion. Look at that week's phrase(s) and describe how it relates to something in your life or how it could apply to certain realistic situations, but I'm open to anything that would drive discussion.